# How to display a empty record error message in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am using a foreach loop to display table records. Below is my code for indexSuccess.php template

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>                    
<?php foreach ($prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs() as $prescriptionDrug): ?>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<tr>
<th class="start"><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getDrug()->getDrugName() ?></th>
<td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getAmountPerTime() ?></td>
<td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getTimesPerDay() ?></td>                                   
<td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreater() ?> (<?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreatedAt() ?>)</td>
</tr>                         
<?php endforeach; ?>  
<?php if($counter==0): ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">No items found</td>
</tr> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't seem to find a way to echo

```
<td colspan="5">No items found</td>
```

when the table is not showing any records.

If i use

```
<?php echo var_dump ($counter); ?>
```

It displays the result below

```
int 1
int 2
int 1
int 2
int 1
int 2
int 1
int 2
int 1
int 2
```

Comment: Maybe try to `var_dump` `$counter` just before the `if` to check its' value.

Comment: It shows array elements, i am not sure why my code is not working. Do you perhaps have an idea why its not working?

Comment: Strange. Can you paste to your question the result of `var_dump($counter)`?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski i have pasted the result on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if($prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs()->count() == 0): ?>  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No items found</td>
    </tr> 
<?php else: ?>       
    <?php foreach ($prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs() as $prescriptionDrug): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="start"><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getDrug()->getDrugName() ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getAmountPerTime() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getTimesPerDay() ?></td>                                   
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreater() ?> (<?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreatedAt() ?>)</td>
        </tr>                         
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "still not working"? Can you better explain? What is the result?

Comment: What i mean is it does not display a message *No items found* when table has no records.

Comment: and if you echo $prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs()->count() what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count() function witch returns you the number of rows.

```
<?php $rows = count($prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs()); ?>   
<?php if($rows==0){ ?>  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No items found</td>
    </tr> 
<?php } else { ?>       
    <?php foreach ($prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs() as $prescriptionDrug): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="start"><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getDrug()->getDrugName() ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getAmountPerTime() ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getTimesPerDay() ?></td>                                   
            <td><?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreater() ?> (<?php echo $prescriptionDrug->getCreatedAt() ?>)</td>
        </tr>                         
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The idea is to display a message **No items found** when table has no records. In my case the table has no records. They is no output to post cause its not doing anything.

Comment: Could you do an var dump on `$prescription->getPrescriptionDrugs()` to if there is any result ?